# Define an emacs function to take arguments in the same way as something like M-x goto-line

Tags: text-editing, functions, commands, insert

I want to write an emacs function for debug purposes in c++ code. Basically I'm fed up typing the following:

```
std::cout << "variable is: " << variable << std::endl;
```

Instead I want to define an emacs function called say "td" for temp debug such that I do

```
M-x td RETURN
foo
```

And it will print

```
std::cout << "foo is: " << foo << std::endl;
```

I want it to behave like `M-x goto-line` whereby I type `M-x goto-line` and press enter then it prompts me for an input, in my case I want my input to be the variable name and something like td instead of goto-line.

Open to other suggestions, but I'd like to know how to code this type of function for future reference anyway.

Comment: Try looking at the source to `goto-line` to see if you can figure it out. Use `C-h f goto-line RET` and click on the link that says `simple.el` to see the source.

Comment: Here are a couple of useful functions which you can combine to get the functionality you're after.  See [`read-minibuffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Object-from-Minibuffer.html#Object-from-Minibuffer) and [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) in the manual.  (And, for good measure here's the [intro to elisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/) you can reference as well.)

Comment: Have you looked into [`yasnippet`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet)

Comment: The "expand <something> into <something else>" concept is called abbrevs in Emacs, and might be worth looking in to.  http://www.emacswiki.org/AbbrevMode

Comment: I'd do that kind of thing with a C++ macro. That way you can easily tell the temporary debug code (`DBG(foo)`) from the normal output, and disable the debug code in production.

Comment: +1 to @Dan's suggestion to read the **Intro to Elisp** manual. Help yourself.

Answer (score 9):

The `interactive` special form provides the easiest way to get input from a user.

```
(defun td (variable)
  (interactive "sVariable:")
  (insert (format "std::cout << \"%s is: \" << %s << std::endl;" variable variable)))
```

Here `"sVariable:"` consists of the `"s"` code character (read a string) and the prompt. (See [Using interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) in the Emacs Lisp Manual for more.)

In addition to using a string with with code characters, the `interactive` special form can use a lisp form as its argument descriptor; this form should evaluate to a list of arguments.

This lets an interactive command compute its arguments from the context, record argument history, and so on.

[`read-from-minibuffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html#Text-from-Minibuffer) supports *both* setting the initial value and recording history; with its help we can make `td` remember what was entered and offer it upon next invocation.

```
(defun td (stream variable)
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-from-minibuffer "Stream: "
                          (when (boundp 'td-history) (car td-history))
                          nil nil 'td-history)
    (read-from-minibuffer "Variable: ")))
  (insert (format "%s << \"%s is: \" << %s << std::endl;" stream variable variable)))
```

PS: Since you are debugging C++ code, you can add `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros, to get something similar to

```
(defun td (variable)
  (interactive "sVariable:")
  (insert (format "std::cout << \"file \" << __FILE__ << \" line \" << __LINE__ << \" %s is: \" << %s << std::endl;" variable variable)))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great. Works really nicely. I modified it to also allow me to specify the stream, e.g. std::err or std::cout etc.
So I have defun td(stream variable) etc.
I would like to know if I can make stream default to the last one I used. In the same way that regexp-search does if you invoke it twice?

Comment: This is how you should do it. But being C++, for maintainability, you'll probably want to format with an error macro (can't use a function of the FILE and LINE macros won't expand right).

Comment: `#define error(v) do { if (debug) std::cerr << "file " << __FILE__ << " line " << __LINE__ << " " #v " is: " << v << std::endl; } while(true)`

Comment: Dang it, past five minutes. I meant `while(0)` I really did.

Answer (score 5):

Like this

```
(defun example(name)
  (interactive "sWhat's your name: ")
  (message "Hello, %s" name))
```

The key part is the `"s"` prefix. Use `s` for plain strings, `b` for buffers, etc.